# How to show widget board Pinterest inserted in website with a 3 or 6 images

Tags: wordpress, pinterest

I have made a widget board with the pinterest developer tools and insert in wordpress website with their code, but when I test the site in google page insights it tells me to postpone the loading of images from the pinterest widget, and it shows me about 30 images.

Does anyone know how to make the widget inserted in website wordpress show only a few images? I've already used lazy load and it doesn't help at all.

I think the problem is the widget that loads all the images from Pinterest,

how could i solve this?

Thank you